# Vectorized computation on Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Currently, I am using the loops to do the task below. It is quite similar to my previous question: [Dot product two 4D Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696531/dot-product-two-4d-numpy-array)

Just wondering if anyone can help me to vectorize the computation without the loops.

```
A1 = np.random.rand(2, 320, 320)
A2 = np.random.rand(15, 2, 320, 320)
B   = np.zeros((2, 320, 320))

for row in range (320):
    for col in range (320):
        C = np.diag(A1[:, row, col]) - (np.dot(A2[:, :, row, col].T, A2[:, :, row, col]) / 15) # the shape of array C is (2, 2)
        C = np.diag(C)                
        B[:, row, col] = C
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you highlight what's new (relative to the previous)?

Comment: apparently, just the new A1 from which the previous output needs to be subtracted. I am not sure if it qualifies as a duplicate, almost does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the last solution -

```
output = A1-(A2*A2).sum(0)/15
np.allclose(output,B)
```

```
True
```